# Magento how to display block outside of body tag

Tags: magento-1.7

My code :

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="test/test" template="test/test.phtml" name="test-test" />
</reference>
```

when i change to

```
<reference name="after_body_end">
    <block type="test/test" template="test/test.phtml" name="test-test" />
</reference>
```

then it is not working. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are referencing ...well...nothing. The block with name `after_body_end` does not exist.
I will explain how to add it but first I want to make it clear that I don't approve of adding html outside the body tag. This may cause issues on some browsers.
First you need to create the block with name `after_body_end`.
For this edit the file app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/layout/page.xml and look for this :

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="before_body_end" as="before_body_end" translate="label">
    <label>Page Bottom</label>
</block>
```

Right under that add the following.

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="after_body_end" as="after_body_end" translate="label">
    <label>Page Unde the body tag</label>
</block>
```

Now your block exists. You just have to add it to your page. For this edit the following files all located in `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/page/`:

- 1column.phtml
- 2columns-left.phtml
- 2columns-right.phtml
- 3columns.phtml
- empty.phtml
- popup.phtml
- print.phtml

For all these files add under the `</body>` line this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_end') ?>
```

Clear the cache and enjoy.